# onResponse(не заходит в метод)

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit

Студия дает ошибку E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout, не заходит в onResponse и поэтому не может прикрепить адаптер.
Как починить?

Mainactivity

```
private ArrayList<User> userList;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private UsersAdapter eAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView text= findViewById(R.id.text);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data.. Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

    ApiService api = RetrofitClient.getApiService();

    Call<UserList> call = api.getUsersJSON();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserList> call, Response<UserList> response) {

            pDialog.dismiss();

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                userList = response.body().getUser();
                recyclerView =  findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                eAdapter = new UsersAdapter(userList);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(eAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserList> call, Throwable t) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

UserList

```
public class UserList {
@SerializedName("")
@Expose
private ArrayList<User> user = null;

public ArrayList<User> getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(ArrayList<User> user) {
    this.user = user;
}
}
```

UsersAdapter

```
public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private List<User> users;

    public UsersAdapter(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.user_list, parent, false);

        return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User user= users.get(position);
        holder.userName.setText(user.getUsername());
        holder.email.setText(user.getEmail());
        holder.name.setText(user.getName());
        holder.iin.setText(user.getIin());
        holder.lastName.setText(user.getLastName());
        holder.phoneNumber.setText(user.getPhone());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView userName,name, email, iin, lastName, phoneNumber;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {


            super(view);
            userName= view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            email = view.findViewById(R.id.email);
            name= view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            lastName = view.findViewById(R.id.lastName);
            iin = view.findViewById(R.id.iin);
            phoneNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

JSON

```
{"username":"user1",
"lastName":"Ivanov",
"name":"Ivan",
"iin":"970624340777",
"phone":"88005553535",
"email":"ivanov.ivan@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: Если в `onResponse` не заходит, значит в `onFailure` заходит - покажите какая там у вас ошибка возникает

Comment: D/myLogs: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Согласно ошибке у вас не тот JSON приходит что вы показали в вопросе. Вам приходит массив чего-то, а вы это пытаетесь в виде объекта распарсить, отчего и ошибка получается

Comment: Сервер дает именно такой ответ в Postman

Comment: Я так понял он ждет объект а получает массив, но я для этого и сделал UserList

Comment: Заменил   Call<UserList> call = api.getUsersJSON(); на Call<List<User>> call = api.getUsersJSON() и через addAll всё заработало